# How to build a Blazor RouteData object from the components Type or Relative Url string

Tags: blazor

I want to pass a specific route for example "/counter" to this component:

```
 <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
```

The @routeData variable, how to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to navigate to that route or do something else? Use a [NavigationManager](https://blazor-university.com/routing/navigating-our-app-via-code/) if you are jut trying to go to that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.  You can't pass a url route to RouteView.  `Router` converts the url route into a `RouteData` object and passes it as a parameter to the `RouteView` component.

RouteData principly contains:

- PageType - the component type to render in the Layout `Body`.
- RouteValues - the parameters obtained from the route.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Since rendering a blazor component (in a webview2) that has a layout, from windows forms does not show the layout and the only way to show the layout is rendering App.razor and then navigate to that component (for example /counter) I wanted to render App.razor first and pass the component route as its parameter to render the target component (/counter).

Comment: Sounds complicated.  Without a lot more detail, I wouldn't know what to suggest.